# send command to custom address

Tags: php, post, get, action

I am trying to make LAN remote for my server.

My server is running at 192.168.0.1.
Going to "192.168.0.1/api/powerstate?newstate=0" toggles the stand-by mode of the server.

I want to make a webpage which in essence is a remote control for the server. So that I can make a button that will reach each toggle of the server.

The problem is, I can't know the servers ip-address before hand.
So users will have to be able to input the correct server ip-address.

QUESTION: How do I go about sending these commands to a user input address?

---

This is what I have done so far:

//HTML form to save the user input ip address

```
<form action="test2.php?saving=1" method="POST">
    <input name="ipadres" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
```

---

//php file

```
<?php
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){
$data = $_POST['ipadres'] . "\n";
$file = "data.txt";

$fp = fopen($file, "w") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");

fclose($fp);
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";

}
?>
```

---

//html button

```
<form action="???/api/powerstate?newstate=0">
    <input type="submit" value="Power Toggle">
</form>
```

How do I retrieve the submitted ip address and put it where the ??? are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['ipadres']) && preg_match('/^(\d+\.){3}\d+$/',$_POST['ipadres'])) {
?>
<form action="//<?=$_POST['ipadres']?>/api/powerstate?newstate=0">
    <input type="submit" value="Power Toggle">
</form>
<?
} else {
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input name="ipadres" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where do I put this, because I can't get it to work.

Comment: you must put this in php file on server (like `index.php` or `form.php`. Any) and open in your browser.

Comment: I have put that in index.php, but it does nothing except save the ipadres to a txt file. www.raiss.nl/stack/